# Custom post category name showing empty

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, categories, theme-development

I have a custom post type and category. I have the below function on my page. I am getting the post but I am not getting the category name on the page.

I am getting the empty array

```
array(0) { }
```

Below is the function code.

```
<?php 
function blogView( $atts ){
  global $post;

  if($atts['cat']=='All'){      
    $blog_post = get_posts(array(
      'showposts' => 80, //add -1 if you want to show all posts
      'post_type' => 'blog'
      ));
  }else{  
    $blog_post = get_posts(array(
      'showposts' => 10, //add -1 if you want to show all posts
      'post_type' => 'blog',
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
      'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cats',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $atts['cat'] //pass your term name here
        )
      ))
       );
  }
     
$data='<ul class="post-grid-list">';
    foreach($blog_post as $t){
    $tid = $t->ID;

         /*Display category code here*/
          $category_detail=get_the_category('4');//$post->ID
          foreach($category_detail as $cd){
          echo $cd->cat_name;
          }
        /*end here*/


         $data.='';

    }
    $data.='</ul>';

    return $data; 

}
add_shortcode( 'blog', 'blogView');
```

Comment: Shortcodes should always return the output and not echo anything - because for example it would cause the block editor to fail in saving a post due to invalid JSON/REST API response - but I guessed the `echo` in your code was just for testing?

Comment: Also, if you did want to retrieve the `category` terms for the post, then have you confirmed that the post did have one or more categories, and does your CPT support the `category` taxonomy?

Comment: @SallyCJ, Echo is for testing purposes. Yes, I have a post with a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `get_the_category()` documentation [stated](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/#description) that:

> Note: This function only returns results from the default "category"
> taxonomy. For custom taxonomies use
> [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/).

So if I guessed it correctly that you're trying to display the `blogs_cats` terms for the current post, then you should use `get_the_terms()` instead.

There's also [`get_the_term_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/) if you just want to display a list of terms like `Foo Bar, Term 2` where each term links to their own archive page.

Examples:

1. Manually loop through the terms returned by `get_the_terms()` to output a simple list of term names (only):

   ```php
   $category_detail = get_the_terms( $tid, 'blogs_cats' );

   $cats = array();
   if ( is_array( $category_detail ) ) {
       foreach ( $category_detail as $cd ) {
           $cats[] = $cd->name;
       }
   }

   $data .= "<li>blogs_cats for $tid: " . implode( ', ', $cats ) . '</li>';
   ```
2. Or use `get_the_term_list()` to output a list of term names + links:

   ```php
   $cat_list = get_the_term_list( $tid, 'blogs_cats', '<i>', ', ', '</i>' );
   $data .= "<li>blogs_cats for $tid: $cat_list</li>";
   ```

Additionally, you should call [`shortcode_atts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) to ensure that the `cat` argument exists in `$atts` (e.g. when using just `[blog]`, i.e. without specifying any parameters). E.g.

```php
function blogView( $atts ){
    global $post;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat' => 'All',
    ), $atts );

    // ... your code.
}
```

Comment: Give me sometime. Let me check

Comment: So have you done checking? Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes, I have tested the first option and I am getting the correct output.  Can you explain the Additionally code? Why you have used then $atts ?

Comment: Well, I used [`shortcode_atts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) to merge the default parameters for the shortcode with the ones supplied, if any, via the shortcode (e.g. `[blog cat="foo"]`). So if the `cat` parameter wasn't supplied, then `shortcode_atts()` ensures `$atts['cat']` is *set*. Please check the link/documentation for more details about the function.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Sure, I will check the documentation

Comment: If I have to show only one category name then what I have to change in this code --->. implode( ', ', $cats )

Comment: Basically, just replace that with `$cats[0]` ... Or replace the entire snippet (in option 1) with `$category_detail = get_the_terms( $tid, 'blogs_cats' ); if ( is_array( $category_detail ) && ! empty( $category_detail ) ) { $data .= '<li>blogs_cats: ' . $category_detail[0]->name . '</li>'; }`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.